# Wordpress slow query on wp_posts inner joined with wp_postmeta

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, performance

I have this query in my main page, which is very slow and it takes 4s to execute. My wp_posts table has 125672 rows and my wp_postmeta has 1405416 rows.
Also every other queries which is inner joining the wp_posts with wp_postmeta is terribly slow.

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'home'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '1' ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'training', 'video', 'startup')
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: There should be an index on wp_postmeta.post_id - can you check that's still there? Have you tried the usual MySQL slow query debugging, e.g. [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) the query? The wp_posts part should be entirely from the type_status_date index so there's a problem if it isn't. I know it shouldn't matter but can you try removing the `1=1` too, just in case that's upsetting something?

Comment: If you want DISTINCT results, use DISTINCT, not GROUP BY. Yes, GROUP BY is faster, but this is not what it's for, and in more complex scenarios you're like a) to make a mistake and b) be unaware of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try rewriting this using `exists`:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM wp_postmeta pm
              WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id AND
                    pm.meta_key = 'home' AND
                    pm.meta_value = '1'
             ) AND
      p.post_type IN ('post', 'training', 'video', 'startup') AND
      p.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

This gets rid of the outer `GROUP BY` (or `SELECT DISTINCT`).

Then, you want indexes.  I would recommend:

- `wp_posts(post_status, post_type, id, post_date)`
- `wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)`

EDIT:

An alternative optimization approach is to start with `wp_postmeta`:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM (SELECT pm.*
      FROM wp_postmeta pm
      WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id AND
            pm.meta_key = 'home' AND
            pm.meta_value = '1'
     ) pm JOIN
     wp_posts p
     ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type IN ('post', 'training', 'video', 'startup') AND
      p.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

For this, you want indexes on `wp_postmeta(meta_key, meta_value, post_id)` and on `posts(id)` (the latter is there by default if `id` is the primary key).

This will work well if the filtering conditions in the subquery are highly selective.

Comment: actually your alternative query runtime had a slice difference with my existing query, the difference was 0.13s which is not very considerable. also adding the indexes didn't improve the run time.

Comment: If `meta_value` is `LONGTEXT`, it cannot be indexed.

Answer (score 2):

- Do you need this?

  GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
- `INDEX(post_status, post_type)` may help
- See my advice on indexes for `post_meta`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta